# Indicating over letters in R

Tags: r

Assume there's a list in R with a variable which contains character fields. I want to output all values which begin with certain letters like "ab". How can I do this? Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you have a `list` or a `data.frame` with a `column`.  If it is the latter, `grep('^ab',yourdata$yourcol, value=TRUE)`

Comment: Oh I'm sorry it is a list.

Comment: If it is a `list`, you can `unlist` (assuming that there is a single string per each list element) i.e. `yourlist[grep('^ab', unlist(yourlist))]` (though it might have been better to show an example instead of asking others to guess the dataset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the OP didn't provide any reproducible example, based on the description, it seems to be a `data.frame`, we can use `grep` to subset the elements in the column that begin with 'ab'.

```
grep('^ab',yourdata$yourcol, value=TRUE)
```